# Refactoring an standard Android code into Reactive code

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

So, I am a newbie Android programmer trying to learn RxJava/RxAndroid.

The App I am developing to study has a local database (using Cupboard) that is backed by an API. It has two screens: one showing a list of items and other the items details. Whenever I need to show the items I call this method to load them from my local database and:

```
public void getItems() {
    List<Item> Items = cupboard().withDatabase(database).query(Item.class).list();

    if (Items == null || Items.isEmpty()) {
        service.listItems().enqueue(new Callback<Items>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Items> call, Response<Items> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    cupboard().withDatabase(database).put(response.body().getItems());
                    mDataReceiver.onItemsLoaded(response.body().getItems());
                } else {
                    Log.d(ItemsLoader.class.getSimpleName(), response.message());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Items> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(ItemsLoader.class.getSimpleName(), t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } else {
        mDataReceiver.onItemsLoaded(Items);
    }
}
```

If nothing (empty list or `null`) is returned, I load them from the API, save it in my local database and returns it to the user.

I was trying to refactor this code into reactive (using RxJava, RxAndroid and RxCupboard) by chaining my database calls with the API call, when need, using flatMap but I just couldn't make it work nor wrap my head around it.

Is it possible to refactor this code into Reactive or should I leave this way? If possible, what would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved with a `PublishSubject`. You can publish data (and errors!) on this object when `onResponse()` or `onFailure()` is called. `PublishSubject` is also an `Observable` so you can subscribe to its data.

See [docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/PublishSubject.html).